# How to insert these element in array

Tags: php, arrays

Suppose an array is give:

```
$given_array=Array(
[0] => 30
[1] => 45
[2] => 60
[3] => 75
[4] => 90
[5] => 105
[6] => 120
[7] => 135)
```

A number is given example: 195

Number until 195 needs to be inserted with a difference of 15

So resulting array is:

```
Array(
[0] => 30
[1] => 45
[2] => 60
[3] => 75
[4] => 90
[5] => 105
[6] => 120
[7] => 135
[8] => 150
[9] => 165
[10] => 180
[11] => 195)
```

Need to know the best approach to do so time required is least.
So far i have tried:

```
 $given_num=195;
if((given_num-$given_array[count($given_array)-1])!=15 && count($given_array)>0){

                    while(($given_array[count($given_array)-1]+15)<=given_num){
                        $given_array[]=$given_array[count($given_array)-1]+15;
                    }

                }
```

Results are correct but not time feasible

Comment: Just to clarify. your first array in the standard and you get a number and you need to add into the standard array until you reach this number?

Comment: Yes with a difference of 15

Comment: you code works if write given_num two times with $ - `$given_num`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that the goal is to have an array with subsequent numbers divisible by 15. Unless you really have to reuse the old array (I wouldn't know why), I 
would suggest creating a new array with `range()`:

`$given_array = range($given_array[0], 195, 15);`

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried yours and not sure whats wrong with it regarding speed but try this.

```
<?php

$given_array=[30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 105, 120, 135];

$newNumber = 195;

$count = floor(($newNumber - $given_array[count($given_array)-1]) / 15);

for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    array_push($given_array, $given_array[count($given_array)-1]+15);
}

print_r($given_array);
```

example: https://3v4l.org/vPiAW

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

```
$given_num = 195;
$last = end($given_array);
while ($given_num > $last) {
    $last = min($last + 15, $given_num);
    $given_array[] = $last;
}
```

But the range-version is quite nice =)

Answer (score 0):

Another short solution using `end` function:

```
while (($last = end($given_array)) < 195) $given_array[] = $last+15;
// now, $given_array contains all the needed items
```